# jQuery replace html/text of an element with others elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have the following td element, with lots of others elements inside it:

```
<td height="43" style="border-bottom:2px solid #2b2b2b;" id="arrow2" >  
<label for="pontoart">Ponto de Articula&ccedil;&atilde;o:</label>
<input type="text" name="pontoart" id="pontoart" value="" required>
<a href="#" id="openbox2" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('+2','','botao de + com hover 2.png',1)">
<img src="botao de + 2.png" alt="" width="24" height="31" id="+2">
</a>
</td>
```

And I have the following jquery function. Basically, it shows a hidden box when a "+" image is clicked. I wanted it to also alter the text to show a little html arrow (code `&#10092;`) when the box is visible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openbox2').click(function(){
        $('#box2').toggle();
        if ($('#box2').is(':visible')) {   
            ?
        }
    });
});
```

I wanted to put a `.text("&#10092;")`inside the if. Problem is, I'm very confused as to what to put in the selector. I wanted the html code to stay the same, only with the ❬ in the end. I already tried all the ids and none gives the result.

```
<td height="43" style="border-bottom:2px solid #2b2b2b;" id="arrow2" >  
    <label for="pontoart">Ponto de Articula&ccedil;&atilde;o:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pontoart" id="pontoart" value="" required>
    <a href="#" id="openbox2" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('+2','','botao de + com hover 2.png',1)">
    <img src="botao de + 2.png" alt="" width="24" height="31" id="+2">
    </a>&#10092;
    </td>
```

Any ideas ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to remove the arrow after you insert it, you can create a new jQuery object of an element with an html entity inside of it, instead of just inserting the html entity into the document with no way of removing it.

- Use `$(this).parent().append(element)` to append our new element to the parent of the clicked element, which in this case would be the `<td>` element.
- Use `jQuery.remove(element)` to remove our new element without deleting it entirely. This means that we can create it again without creating a new jQuery object.

```js
var arrow = $('<span>&#10092;</span>');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#openbox2').click(function() {
    $('#box2').toggle();
    if ($('#box2').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).parent().append(arrow);
    } else {
      arrow.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="43" style="border-bottom:2px solid #2b2b2b;" id="arrow2">
      <label for="pontoart">Ponto de Articula&ccedil;&atilde;o:</label>
      <input type="text" name="pontoart" id="pontoart" value="" required>
      <a href="#" id="openbox2" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="//placehold.it/24x31" alt="" width="24" height="31" id="+2">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="box2" style="display:none">Hello foo bar world!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the trick! Sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$("#arrow2").append("&#10092;");
```

That would add the arrow at the end of your td.

Comment: This works, but adds a new arrow everytime the box is visible. But I guess it only needs a .remove() to eliminate the extra arrows :)) thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openbox2').click(function(){
        $('#box2').toggle();
        if ($('#box2').is(':visible')) {   
           $(this).closest('td').find('label').append('&#10092;')
        } else {
           $(this).closest('td').find('label')...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery `after` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to place ❬ after the `a` tag.

```
$('#openbox2').after('&#10092;');
```